# JQuery UI Datepicker: Making a link trigger datepicker

Tags: jquery-ui, hyperlink, datepicker

I am using JQuery's UI datepicker: http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/

implemented here:

http://www.clients.eirestudio.net/old/

I want to use a link as the trigger but I can't get it to work.

Here is my code:

```
// JQuery UI
$("#datepicker").datepicker({
      changeMonth: true,
      changeYear: true,
      maxDate: '0m 0d',
      minDate: new Date(2000, 1 - 1, 1),
      dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy'
});

<p class="clearfix hidden">
    <input id="" class="input float datepicker" type="input" name="" value="" />
    <a class="calendar ui-icon ui-icon-calendar">Date</a>

    <span class="mid-info">To</span>
    <input id="" class="input datepicker" type="input" name="" value="" />
    <a class="calendar" href="#">Date</a>
</p>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This might help somebody else.

I ended up getting it to work with JQuery UI.

Code below:

```
$(".date-pick").datepicker({
      changeMonth: true,
      changeYear: true,
      maxDate: '0m 0d',
      minDate: new Date(2000, 1 - 1, 1),
      dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
      showOn: 'button', 
      buttonImage: 'http://www.example.com/elements/images/calendar.png', 
      buttonImageOnly: true
      });
```

and I changed the datepicker id to date-pick class

Comment: What HTML did you end up with?  Did you add the date-pick class to the links as well?  Having trouble with this on my end.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question at all lol.  This isn't using a link to trigger the calendar - it's just using the buttonImage to open it.  Still requires an input field which you may or may not even have...

Answer (score 27):

You could do something like I did in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gnarf/dsbyX/2/)

HTML:

```
<a href="#" id="toggleDP">Toggle</a>
```

JS:

```
var $dp = $("<input type='text' />").hide().datepicker({
    onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
       $("body").append("<div>Selected "+dateText+"</div>");
    }
}).appendTo('body');

$("#toggleDP").button().click(function(e) {
    if ($dp.datepicker('widget').is(':hidden')) {
        $dp.show().datepicker('show').hide();
        $dp.datepicker("widget").position({
            my: "left top",
            at: "right top",
            of: this
        });
    } else {
        $dp.hide();
    }

    //e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: This solution doesn't appear to work in Chrome 29 with jQuery 1.9

Comment: Works for me on chrome, the only issue I have is that it scrolls me to the bottom, so I edited it to add the datepicker only once when clicking the link and appending it to the current clicked element's parent.

Answer (score 18):

I just solved this very easily in my app -- if you have your datepicker open with a text field, you can use this solution too. I added a `$('#date_field').focus()` link to the icon. Click the icon, the text field gets focus and that triggers the datepicker to open. Voila.

Comment: i like this solution, quick and easy.

Comment: Thanks! This technique is also useful to create a simple button that opens the datepicker on click (without the extra side button that is created if you use the `onShow: "button"` datepicker parameter), like so:  `<input id="date" type="button" onclick="this.focus()">` where elsewhere you do the normal `$("#date").datepicker()`.

Comment: This is the correct answer, allowing for easily maintainable code.

Answer (score 7):

Try using:

```
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="$.datepicker._showDatepicker($('#inputID')[0]);">Text here</a>
    <input type="hidden" id="inputID"/>
    ...
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(
         function()
         {
             $('#inputID').datepicker();
         }
      );
    </script>
```

Comment: By far the simplest solution with the least added code and hijinks. Thank you!

Comment: Yep, I like this one :) +1

Answer (score 4):

Based on @camilokawerin answer, I did this and I find it the easieast and cleanest solution:

HTML:

```
<a href="#" id="selec">Click</a> <div id="datepicker" style="display:none"></div>
```

JS:

```
$("#datepicker").datepicker();
$('#selec').click(function(){
    $('#datepicker').toggle();
});
```

Comment: Seems nice but how do you obtain the selected date?

Comment: @tiho I pick it up in the `onSelect` method... Everything is in the docs
http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-onSelect

Answer (score 0):

From [jqueryui](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#icon-trigger), it seems like you should add `showOn` and maybe (don't know if it's required) `buttonImage`:

```
$("#datepicker").datepicker({
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    maxDate: '0m 0d',
    minDate: new Date(2000, 1 - 1, 1),
    dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
    showOn: 'button', 
    buttonImage: 'images/calendar.gif', // adapt this to your image
    buttonImageOnly: true
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Unfortunately I tried that and it doesn't seem to work also.

Comment: I somehow forgot the `datepicker()` function before, and the `buttonImage` property must probably be adapted, as your own answer suggests. Sorry about the inaccuracy.

Answer (score 0):

With [inline datepicker](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#inline) is pretty easier to do this. Check my [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3vV3E/1/).

HTML

```
<a href="#" class="datepicker">Pick a date</a>
```

JS

```
var dpToggler = $('a.datepicker').button(),
    dp = $("<div />").css('position', 'absolute').hide().datepicker().appendTo(dpToggler);

dpToggler.on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  if (dp.is(':hidden')) {
    dp.show().position({
      my: 'left top',
      at: 'right top',
      of: this
    });
  } else {
    dp.hide();
  }
});
```