# Can JQuery UI datepicker be bound to an icon?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have  some HTML that looks like

```
<select id="day"><option>Day</option></select>
<select id="month"><option>Month</option></select>
<select id="year"><option>Year</option></select>
<img src="img/some-icon.png" id="datepicker" />
```

I'm unable to bind `$("#datepicker").datepicker()` to the icon above. It's just wouldn't display the calendar.

JQuery UI examples are always bind the datepicker to an input field. I just wanted to know is there an alternative way to achieve this?

**EDIT: I'm currently using a hidden field as many suggested below. Just wanted to know if there was a way for me to avoid using a hidden field**

Comment: are the 3 selects somehow relevant?

Comment: yes they get populated with the date selected. :)

Comment: how do you do this? :)

Comment: @Zim84 -  see here - http://jsfiddle.net/gvAbv/13/

Comment: Sorry to ask, but ... why? :D

Comment: You asked how I populate the 3 drop downs with date selected. Above fiddle shows how it's done.

Comment: hope this link will be helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2198741/jquery-ui-datepicker-making-a-link-trigger-datepicker

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone is interested in knowing how I created the plugin for this, follow the code below. I had to work with having a hidden field in the end but it did turn out to be the only way I could find to work with the calendar successfully.

HTML

```
<select id="day"><option>Day</option></select>
<select id="month"><option>Month</option></select>
<select id="year"><option>Year</option></select>
<input type="hidden" id="date-selector">
```

JavaScript

```
$.fn.showCalendar = function(options){
    var defaults ={
        selector : "#date-selector",
        calendarIcon : "./images/icons/calendar.gif",
        numberOfSelectableDays : "+60D",
        dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy",
        numberOfMonths : 3,
        daySelector : "#day",
        monthSelector : "#month",
        yearSelector : "#year"
    }

    var $this = $(this);
    var params = $.extend({},defaults, options);

    var getDateFromDropDowns = function(){
         var dateOnDropDowns =  new Date($(params.daySelector).val(),$(params.monthSelector).val(),$(params.yearSelector).val());
         return  dateOnDropDowns;
    }


    return $this.each(function(){
        $this.datepicker({
            showOn: "button",
            buttonImage: params.calendarIcon,
            minDate: 0,
            maxDate: params.numberOfSelectableDays,
            dateFormat: params.dateFormat,
            buttonImageOnly: true,
            numberOfMonths: params.numberOfMonths,
            setDate : getDateFromDropDowns,
            onClose: function(dateText, inst) {
                $(params.yearSelector).val(dateText.split('/')[2]);
                $(params.daySelector).val(dateText.split('/')[0]);
                $(params.monthSelector).val(dateText.split('/')[1]);
            }
        });
    });
},
```

Answer (score 1):

You missed open `"` of your `id`, should be:

```
<img src="img/some-icon.png" id="datepicker" />
--------------------------------^here-----------
```

Comment: Thanks edited. That was a typo in the question but the actual HTML is OK :)

Answer (score 0):

An alternative would be to let the control be bound to an input field. Make this hidden. And then `onclick` of your icon, simply call `onFocus()` of the input field.

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I'm currently doing. I wanted to confirm if there was a way to avoid using the hidden field.

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="text" id="datepicker"/>
<img src="img/some-icon.png" id="datepick" />
```

Use the above code to show the calender. If you want to hide the textbox then use type="hidden".

To click the hidden textbox use below JS code.

```
$("#datepick").click(function(){
     $("#datepicker").click();
     $("#datepicker").datepicker();
});
```