# Show jQuery DatePicker on click on anchor

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

I'm using jQuery datepicker, and I want to show the it when I click on an anchor, and I want to hide the input which is associated to the datepicker event.

So I tried this

```
<a id="test">
   test
</a>

<p>Date: <input type="hidden" id="TafPassportDateOfIssue" /></p>
```

And I have this script

```
<script>
  $('#test').click(function() {
    $('#TafPassportDateOfIssue').datepicker();
  });
```

But this doesn't do anything. Any ideas ?

PS : I am using **jquery-1.7.2.min.js** and **jquery-ui-1.8.11.min.js**

**Update:**

I managed to make it work by adding `$('#TafPassportDateOfIssue').focus()`. I know it seems a bit messy but it gets the job done.

Comment: you missed `#` -- > `$('#TafPassportDateOfIssue').datepicker();`

Comment: Sorry no that was just a typing error when writing the question. Even with the # it doesn't work

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JQuery UI Datepicker: Making a link trigger datepicker](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2198741/jquery-ui-datepicker-making-a-link-trigger-datepicker)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Invalid `Jquery` selector.There is no `#` in your `selector` since you are selecting with ID

it should be  `$('#TafPassportDateOfIssue')`  not  `$('TafPassportDateOfIssue')`

So,change your code to

```
$('#test').click(function() {
    $('#TafPassportDateOfIssue').datepicker();
  });
```

Comment: Sorry that was just a typing error when writing the question. I updated my question. Even with the `#` it doesn't work.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2198741/jquery-ui-datepicker-making-a-link-trigger-datepicker

Comment: Who said its mess.I did'nt find any scaring lines there.Don't worry.

Answer (score 1):

`datepicker()` makes the input element a datepicker, but doesn't show it. This way every time the link is clicked, the function would try to apply a datepicker to the input element, but would not actually do so, because it also adds a class `hasDatepicker` to it. If the element already got the class, the function returns instead of reapplying the datepicker.

The jQuery UI datepicker plugin has an option to open it on click on a button to it: `showOn: 'button'`

So use this, if this is what you actually try to achieve.