# JQuery / Bootstrap datepicker on click dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datepicker, bootstrap-4

I'm new to front end development so forgive my ignorance here, but I have Bootstrap dropdown menus and when the user clicks on them, I want it to pull up the datepicker so the user can select a date. Then I'll eventually pass the menu selection and date selection into variables, but I can't even get to the point where I can get the datepicker to pop up when selecting the menu.

Below are a couple examples of what I've tried, though I've tried quite a few different techniques. The first one I got from Pere's suggestion on this thread [JQuery UI Datepicker: Making a link trigger datepicker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2198741/jquery-ui-datepicker-making-a-link-trigger-datepicker) but I get an error saying datepicker is not a function when I run it. I'm sure someone here will look at this right away and be able to figure out what I'm doing wrong, so please help me out.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#datepicker').datepicker()
    $('.dropdown-item').click(function () {
            $('#datepicker').toggle()
    });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


            
 <div class="btn-group">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
        Menu
    </button>
      <div class="dropdown-menu">
          <a class="dropdown-item" id="1">1</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" id="2">2</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" id="3">3</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" id="4">4</a>
          <input type=date id=datepicker>
       </div>
</div>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#datepicker').hide()
    $('.dropdown-item').click(function () {
            $('#datepicker').show()
    });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


            
 <div class="btn-group">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
        Menu
    </button>
      <div class="dropdown-menu">
          <a class="dropdown-item" id="1">1</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" id="2">2</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" id="3">3</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" id="4">4</a>
          <input type=date id=datepicker>
       </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Where is datepicker defined? It doesn't look like you've included the script for it.

Comment: Sorry, I'm really not too experienced with JQuery, but I thought it was a pre-defined function in JQuery? On here it doesn't look like they're defining it beyond just calling it:

http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#icon-trigger

Comment: thats jQueryUI - a whole different set of tools for using _wth_ jQuery... You need to download it and add the relevant script tags into your head.

Comment: Sigh... Thanks for your patience. Let's see if I can get it to work now that I have the correct library.

Comment: I got the right script in there now, but I still can't get this to work. Can anyone offer any tips? I'm really frustrated that this is not working. :(

Comment: I don't need JQuery UI, Datepicker is included in Bootstrap which I'm already using, and there are conflicts between JQuery UI and Datepicker. So I'm back to square one...

Answer (score 0):

If anyone stumbles upon the same problem as me, after pulling my hair out all day, below is what I finally settled on and it works! It returns both the date and the dropdown row's ID, so I will be able to pass that into my larger application.

```html
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Datepicker</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="../static/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
    <link href="../static/bootstrap-datepicker.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {

            $('.dropdown-item').datepicker({
                format: 'mm/dd/yyyy'
            });

            $('.dropdown-item').on('changeDate', function (event) {
                alert(this.id + ' ' + event.format());
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<div class="btn-group">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
        Menu
    </button>
    <div class="dropdown-menu">
        <a class="dropdown-item" id="1">1</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" id="2">2</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" id="3">3</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" id="4">4</a>
        <input id=datepicker />
    </div>
</div>
</html>
```